# How can I make grep respects colors on a pipe?

Tags: linux, bash

In a modern Linux shell, lots of commands (like `ls`) can output colored text.

If you pipe it with other commands, you lose the color. E.g:

```
$ ls path
[... folders in blue, executables in green,..etc ]

$ ls path | grep foo
[... all in black and white]
```

How can I make the `grep` on the second part of the pipe respect the `ls` colors (or any other command executed)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can tell `ls` to always color the output, since when it's writing to a pipe with `--color=auto` it does not add color.

If you do `ls --color=always path | grep --color=never foo` it will make `ls` add color, and prevent `grep` from replace with its own colors.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work with `git branch | grep --color=never -v trash`

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat `git branch --color=always | grep --color=never -v trash` works for me, if it doesn't for you please ask a new question

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it works. It's better than the horrible workaround I've been using `git branch --sort=-committerdate | grep -v trash | perl -pe 's{^\*(.*)}{*\033[32m$1 \033[0m}g'` (which trying to assign with zsh's `bindkey` was a nightmare with all the apostrophies).

Answer (score 0):

Both commands have a `--color=always` argument.

```
$ ls --color=always | grep e
```

Comment: Eric solution is more completed. I need --color=never on grep command to work.

Comment: Anyone know where/how the auto flavor is implemented? It has to be more than a shell feature, built in to some library they all use for color. Is there any way to change how auto classifies the output channel? Would be nice to customize it, but you probably have to change something deep in a library to do it. It would then take a while before the support propagates to all the tools and distributions.

Comment: @GerryGleason looking at the source for `ls` it sure looks like it's all built right into it, not in a library.  It's not a shell feature, nor does it seem to be a library common to coreutils or anything like that.  I guess that each app is building it themselves, at least looking in coreutils-8.24

Comment: I have `nginx -V |grep  --color=always ssl` and `ssl` is not colorized in the output. How can I do that?